# Is Alfresco's ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase LDAP query recursive?

Tags: alfresco

In Alfresco, I want to specify that all users found under a particular `DN` should be considered as valid Alfresco users.

Problem: My users are split in many different `OU` sub-levels.

Will Alfresco be able to recursively find all users if I specify the `DN` as `ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you're after. Assuming I'm correct, you've got the same setup we have, and the simple answer is "Yes, it works"

Let's try for some ASCII art of a directory tree:

```
Root
  |--->Computers
  |--->Special Accounts
  |--->Accounts (*)
       |-->Head Office Users
       |     |->Jim Smith
       |     |->Jane Jones
       |     |->Admin
       |-->Sales Office Users
       |     |->Anne Blogs
       |-->Remote Users
       |     |->Tom Blogs
       |-->Groups
             |->Admins
             |->Normal Users
```

What I think you want is to have all of your users (head office, sales, remote etc) synced with Alfresco, and all the groups, but you want to avoid having accounts created for computers etc?

If so, set the sync to start at `ou=Accounts,dc=root` (ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase and ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase) and it should just work